# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.providers.snowflake.transfers.s3_to_snowflake'

Tags: python, docker, airflow

**Context**

I'm trying to setup an airflow/dbt docker infrastructure with Snowflake as a database, AWS S3 as a file management system and MongoDB as a data source.

**Issue**

I installed `apache-airflow-providers-snowflake`, I can find `airflow.providers.snowflake.transfers.copy_into_snowflake` but **can't find** `airflow.providers.snowflake.transfers.s3_to_snowflake` !

Here's what I get as an error on my main dag :

[ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.providers.snowflake.transfers.s3_to_snowflake'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnu4x.png)

***Have you ever had the same issue importing snowflake providers and only getting copy_into_snowflake component ?***

**Source code (I can give you more details if needed)**

Here's my project directory tree :

```
project
|
|-- airflow
    |-- dags
        |-- main.py
    |-- Dockerfile
    |-- requirements.txt
|
|-- docker-compose.yaml
|-- .env
```

Airflow main dag :

```py
import pendulum
from airflow.providers.snowflake.transfers.s3_to_snowflake import S3ToSnowflakeOperator

from airflow import DAG

with DAG(
    dag_id="main",
    start_date=pendulum.datetime(year=2024, month=3, day=26, hour=15, minute=35),
    schedule_interval="15 4 * * *",
    catchup=False,
) as dag:
    pass
```

Comment: have you installed snowflake provider?

Answer (score 0):

taking a look at the docs, it seems the `airflow.providers.snowflake.transfers.s3_to_snowflake` module is only available in versions prior to 4.4.2. If you are using a newer version, it probably won't work.

Comment: Thanks a lot Salah. As said above, I was looking to an old version of the documentation, sorry for the inconvenience :) !

Answer (score 0):

This was removed from `apache-airflow-providers-snowflake` in 5.0.0 in favor of [`airflow.providers.snowflake.transfers.copy_into_snowflake.CopyFromExternalStageToSnowflakeOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-snowflake/stable/_api/airflow/providers/snowflake/transfers/copy_into_snowflake/index.html#airflow.providers.snowflake.transfers.copy_into_snowflake.CopyFromExternalStageToSnowflakeOperator), see [Changelog](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-snowflake/stable/changelog.html#breaking-changes)

The more details about operator could be found into the https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-snowflake/stable/operators/copy_into_snowflake.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Andrey. I've found out I was reading 2.3.1 documentation of this package... I feel so dumb lol. Have a good day